# Is this too much Protein?

Tags: supplements

I am tall 192cm (6'4") and I weigh 100kg

I use Protein shake after gym around 30gm of Protein
and because I go to gym late night,
immediately after gym i eat 2 cans of Tuna ( around 15gm Protein each) then drink Milk then go to bed.
In the morning I eat a sandwich and light lunch at work and eat a medium meal around 6 pm

is this too much Protein for me?
shall I stop the night tuna because I already had the Protein shake?

Comment: Are you getting more than 0.8g protein per lbs of bodyweight? If you're 100kg, ideally you'll want to consume around 175g protein (though honestly, I'd go about 150g to 175g)

Comment: Plus, you say "a sandwich and a light lunch" with no details so we don't even know how much protein you are getting. This queation has been answered before, I will mark it when I am not on mobile.